# simpledialog2 automatically closes

Tags: android, jquery-mobile, cordova

Android, Phonegap, Jquery Mobile

When I open simpledialog it shows and destroys, **it doesn't happen when debugging in browser**, but happens, when launching app on phone. Also the funny part is that it's not happening all the time, but when it starts to happen it happens each time you open this simpledialog. Only thing you can do to fix it is to restart app. As far as I found out, on dialog show it's automatically fires button event, which closes dialog. 
Maybe it's not related to the problem, but when dialog is closed, it fires close event twice and I get js error: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'destroy' of undefined` 
Can anyone help ?

Comment: Without code almost no one can help. Add more info if you want this question answered.

Comment: I guess this is starting to happen when you try to open a dialog box more than once in quick succession

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue. Clearly the dialog is no longer on the page since it is undefined per that error message. I added this simple check when my dialog need to be closed, to check if it's still on the page:

```
function close_simple_dialog() {
  if(typeof $.mobile.sdCurrentDialog !== "undefined"){
    $.mobile.sdCurrentDialog.close();
  }
});
```